# SSIS Package Execution From Visual Studio Unit Test

Tags: sql-server, ssis, entity-framework

Hello I am attempting to run a test which contains the following code:

```
        string pkgLocation;
        Package pkg;
        Application app;
        DTSExecResult pkgResults;



        pkgLocation =
          @"C:\Users\mYCoMppp\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\packageOnExeCreatesTable" +
          @"\Integration Services Project8\Package.dtsx";
        app = new Application();
        pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
        pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

        Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

This is an attempt to populate a table which has had all of its records removed thanks to the test I ran before it. I am not getting any errors - however it does take a while to complete the test. I do not know exactly how long it takes, because the test is running as I type this.

So alas, my question. I would like to know if anybody out there can explain to me if this is a time consuming way of executing a package. And also if anybody knows of any other way to execute SSIS packages faster.

Comment: I answer the SSIS questions over here too ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298938/ssis-package-execution-from-visual-studio-unit-test

Comment: thats fine and dandy. I havent found a solution yet. and its still literally trying to finish.. but i really dont think it will..

Answer (score 0):

First thing write another package that does a simple file copy task for example and see if that takes a long time using your same call method. If it does then perhaps your call method could be improved. I suspect it will be quick and the package code is where the problem is, not how its called.